# Android Polymorphism: Anti-Pattern?

Tags: java, android, polymorphism

I'm reading O'Reilly's "Programming Android" book, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the "Overrides and Callbacks" section starting on page 99. They use this as an example of good code:

```
public class MyModel {
    public MyModel(TextView textBox) {
        textBox.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    handleTextChange(s);
                }
                // ...
    }
    void handleTextChange(Editable s) {
        // do something with s, the changed text.
    }
}
```

And later call this an anti-pattern due to lack of <strike>extensibility</strike> encapsulation:

```
public class MyModel implements TextWatcher {
    public MyModel(TextView textBox) {
        textBox.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        handleTextChange(s);
    }

    // ...

    void handleTextChange(Editable s) {
        // do something with s, the changed text.
    }
}
```

I don't see the functional difference between the two, aside from the second being a lot more readable. Both take a TextView, and implement a handler function to override. Wouldn't the second be just as easy to extend with something like this?

```
public class AnotherModel extends MyModel {
    @Override
    void handleTextChange(Editable s) {
         // another implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I would implement TexWatcher if and only if MyModel will contain alot of textboxes that will share a common TextWatcher; otherwise I would use alot of anonymous inner-classes; or define one and re-use it. No need to pollute MyModel class with those callbacks in this context really.

Comment: Withdrew my answer (even though I was getting upvoted 8-(  ) since it did not address this specific example.

Answer (score 2):

> an anti-pattern due to lack of extensibility

Extensibility-wise, they're similar in that both approaches let a subclass easily modify the existing `TextChangeListener` by overriding `handleTextChange`; but they're different in that only approach #2 also makes it easy for a subclass to add a *new* `TextChangeListener` without modifying the existing (inherited) one.

Even if the superclass uses approach #1, the subclass could still add a new `TextChangeListener` by using approach #2; but if we're talking about the pattern to use in general, then a consistent use of approach #2 will afford more extensibility than a consistent use of approach #1.

Comment: I don't see how #2 is easier to add a new listener, in either case simply calling super in the constructor will accomplish this as this is where the existing listener is registered.

Comment: @Robin: Right -- and the compiler will actually force you to call `super` explicitly, because there's no no-arg constructor -- but if you're using approach #1, then your notation for adding a new listener is to write `textBox.addTextChangedListener(this);`, which won't work: you'll just be adding the same object as a new listener, and there's no way to have one listener do one thing while the other listener does another.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't like the 2nd form, since the class implements an interface as a trick, not because the class naturally is a subtype of the interface.

The 2nd form can be manageable for simple cases, so it's ok unless it gets too messy.

In Java 8, we can use the 1st form in a better syntax:

```
    textBox.addTextChangedListener(this#handleTextChange);  // method reference
```

Comment: Ahh, lightbulb. Their MyModel class is actually designed to do more than one thing, it's just not shown in this example. If it was a simple class, such as MyTextWatcher, it'd be more of a valid use, but since the real class would do more than that, implementing the interface directly is more of a trick. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use the method reference syntax, because `TextWatcher` has three abstract methods, not one. Of course unless they add `default` implementations for `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()` in a future version of Android.